# omit multiple keys by wildcard or regex during compare

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

When i want to exclude some properties in a json object that contain a set of characters, how can i do this?

```
var obj1 = {name: "James", age: 17, creation: "13-02-2016", deletion: "13-04-2016", foo_x:"", foo_y:"", foo_z:""}
var obj2 = {name: "Maria", age: 17, creation: "13-02-2016", deletion: "13-04-2016", foo_x:"", foo_y:"", foo_z:""}
```

so now i want to remove all properties that contains the string `foo`

```
var result = _.isEqual(
  _.omit(obj1, ['\*foo\*']),
  _.omit(obj2, ['\*foo\*'])
);
```

something like this...

Is there a way i can do this?

Answer (score 4):

In vanilla JS,

May be not the best approach. But you can do this in the way

1. Filter the keys having `foo` etc
2. Get key value pairs from the original array based on the filtered key
3. Create a final object

```js
var obj1 = {name: "James", age: 17, creation: "13-02-2016", deletion: "13-04-2016", foo_x:"", foo_y:"", foo_z:""}
var obj2 = {name: "Maria", age: 17, creation: "13-02-2016", deletion: "13-04-2016", foo_x:"", foo_y:"", foo_z:""};

var o = Object.keys(obj1).filter(o=> !o.includes('foo')),
    i = o.map(i=> ({[i] : obj1[i]})),
    obj =  Object.assign({}, ...i);
    console.log(obj)
```

Comment: @Gobliins, this is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a function to omit that takes the key as the second parameter:

```
const result = _.omit(obj1, (value, key) => key.includes('foo'))
```

Comment: Isn't it omitBy?

Comment: omitBy is a lodash function, the question is about underscore

Comment: Any reason for the downvote today? If you let me know what is wrong with the answer I will fix it. Nobody learns from anonymous downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following (it manipulates the same object)

```js
function removeProps (obj, prop) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if(key.indexOf(prop) !== -1) delete obj[key];
  });
}
var obj1 = {name: "James", age: 17, creation: "13-02-2016", deletion: "13-04-2016", foo_x:"", foo_y:"", foo_z:""};

removeProps(obj1, "foo");
console.log(obj1);
```

In case you wish to preserve the object

```js
function removeProps (obj, prop) {
  obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if(key.indexOf(prop) !== -1) delete obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
}
var obj1 = {name: "James", age: 17, creation: "13-02-2016", deletion: "13-04-2016", foo_x:"", foo_y:"", foo_z:""};

var obj1Updated = removeProps(obj1, "foo");
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj1Updated);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you need the solution using regex so here you go:

```
var obj1 = {name: "James", age: 17, creation: "13-02-2016", deletion: "13-04-2016", foo_x:"", foo_y:"", foo_z:""}
var obj2 = {name: "Maria", age: 17, creation: "13-02-2016", deletion: "13-04-2016", foo_x:"", foo_y:"", foo_z:""};

Object.prototype.filterRegex = function(regex) {
    // check if regex is passed
    let filtered = Object.keys(this).filter((key) => !regex.test(key));
    return filtered.reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = this[key];
        return obj;
    }, {});
};

obj1.filterRegex(/foo/);
obj2.filterRegex(/foo/);
```